# How do I change the background of the side pane?

Tags: nautilus-elementary, themes

How do I go about changing the white background on nautilus-elementary's side pane?

I want to change it specifically to match the color of the toolbar and status-bar.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file (create one if it doesn't exist):

```
style "nautilus-sidepane"
{
    GtkTreeView::even_row_color   = "#F2F1F0"
}

widget_class "*NautilusSidePane*" style "nautilus-sidepane"
```

Then log out and back in (or restart Nautilus with `nautilus -q`, or change to another theme and back to the old one).

Comment: Do I have to do something (other than write this to `~/.gtkrc-2.0`) to get it displaying?

Comment: @Oli: Updated the answer.

Comment: By the way, I submitted your answer to OMG!ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, I wish i could make that work.
I did exactly what adviced, but even after reboot it looks the same:
[screenshot](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6506/bildschirmfotooo.png)

What can went wrong? Maybe this file has to be placed in a different folder than /home ?
Any Ideas?

Comment: Nothing went wrong - you just have to put in the color you want instead of #F2F1F0 (which is the side pane color in your screenshot).

Comment: is there a way to edit this file to also change the font color in the sidebar?  i am using elementary theme, and the font color is grey, i would like to change it to black.