# Change side pane color in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, themes, customization

I've recently [changed the sidebar color in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21784/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-the-side-pane) to match the theme. Is there something I could do similar for Rhythmbox? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it's not much different from changing the color of the Nautilus-Elementary sidebar.

Add the following to your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file (create one if it doesn't exist):

```
style "rb-sidebar"
{
    GtkTreeView::even_row_color   = "#F2F1F0"

}
widget_class  "*RBSourceList*"  style "rb-sidebar"
```

Then switch to a different theme and then back to your old one.

As you can see in the screenshot below, there is a border around the sidebar in Rhythmbox unlike in Nautilus-Elementary, but the color matching does improve how Rhythmbox looks, in my opinion.

[image]